# Out of Memory Error con JRE recien instalado

Tags: java, java-8

Después de haber instalado un JRE en una máquina con Debian, al intentar consultar la versión instalada de java me aparece un error. Si abro el log aparece mas o menos lo siguiente como información relevante

```
Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2640), pid=25857

Java Threads: ( => current thread )

Other Threads:

=>0x00000286f000a000 (exited) JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=25858, stack(0x00000286f7800000,0x00000286f7900000)]

VM state:not at safepoint (not fully initialized)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Classes redefined (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (0 events):
No events

Events (0 events):
No events
```

Sin embargo, no parece que falte memoria

```
OS:DISTRIB_ID=Debian
DISTRIB_RELEASE=8
DISTRIB_CODENAME=
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION=

uname:Linux 3.14.32-xxxx-grspax-ipv6-64 #5 SMP Wed Jan 20 14:02:38 CET 2016 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.27 NPTL 2.27 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 63764, NOFILE 1048576, AS infinity
load average:0.20 0.14 0.15

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:       16324948 kB
MemFree:        14393508 kB
MemAvailable:   14505700 kB
Buffers:           31932 kB
Cached:          1123712 kB
SwapCached:         2016 kB
Active:           589980 kB
Inactive:        1063640 kB
Active(anon):     481040 kB
Inactive(anon):  1039532 kB
Active(file):     108940 kB
Inactive(file):    24108 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:        523260 kB
SwapFree:         443352 kB
Dirty:               236 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        497292 kB
Mapped:           132724 kB
Shmem:           1022596 kB
Slab:              93588 kB
SReclaimable:      39020 kB
SUnreclaim:        54568 kB
KernelStack:        5008 kB
PageTables:        13000 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     8685732 kB
Committed_AS:    3467272 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      119116 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359461644 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
DirectMap4k:        5936 kB
DirectMap2M:    16676864 kB
```

La ejecución está hecha como root, por lo que no debería haber problemas de usuarios ni nada raro. ¿Que puede ser?

Un saludo.

Comment: Supongo que lo que has hecho es `java -version`, ¿no es así? En ese caso es muy raro, suena a problema de instalación, o quizás incluso del SO o HW. Es uno de esos casos en que reinstalar parece la mejor opción.

Comment: Así es, tras instalar con apt-get install lancé el comando java -version y aparece un error de memoria y se genera ese log.

Comment: Es un error en tu jre, deberías de reportarlo a la gente de Oracle, o bajar un build posterior.